# How to press enter in input type text call function javascript by not submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How to press `enter` in input type text call function javascript by not submit form ?

When fill data into input type text and press `enter keyboard` i want only to call function `detect_enter_keyboard(event)` by not to submit form.

How can i do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/atuyx7qc/

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="user" onkeypress="detect_enter_keyboard(event)">
<input name="btnLogin" onclick="test_fn();" type="button" value="Send">
</form>

<script>
function detect_enter_keyboard(event) {
    var key_board_keycode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(key_board_keycode == 13)
    {
        test_fn();
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function test_fn(){
alert("555555");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`preventDefault()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp). Add this line after `if(key_board_keycode == 13)`:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: by this way, I can not fill data into input.

Comment: @mongmongmongseesee Right, then you need to place the `preventDefault()` right after detecting if the pressed key is `enter`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```js
function detect_enter_keyboard(event) {

    var key_board_keycode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(key_board_keycode == 13)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        test_fn();
    }
}
function test_fn(){
    alert("555555");
}
```

```html
<form >
<input type="text" name="user" onkeypress="detect_enter_keyboard(event)">
<input name="btnLogin" onclick="test_fn();" type="button" value="Send">
</form>
```